# Pcl ros image extraction

Tags: ros, pcl, extract-images

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have extracted an object of interest using Euclidean Cluster Extraction in PCL. I would now like to extract the corresponding object in a 2D image that has been saved simultaneously. Are there any tools available in ros/pcl that can be used to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193547/pcl-ros-image-extraction/) by [pnambiar](https://answers.ros.org/users/15286/pnambiar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2014-09-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PCL has tools to generate an image from the point cloud directly ([basic](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros/Tutorials/CloudToImage) or [range image](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/range_image_creation.php)), however not for dealing with two parallel objects. The above links will work if you're willing to take a hit in quality, but if you want to work with the original RGB image, you'll have to do some manual calculations.

You could [project](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/project_inliers.php) the pointcloud onto a plane representing the rectified* image, and use the points to mark which pixels you want to 'keep'. Or just project the bounding box and.

*: I am not a vision expert, so this may not be rigorous

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0